# In Flutter, how to catch detail of NULL exception?

Tags: flutter, bloc

In my project, I use BLOC pattern with **Stream**. That stream watch `Loading`, `Data` and `Error` state then show to UI that states.

- At first scenario, if in model file there is contain `null` value, UI only show loading state and in console show the detail of which API value contain null value. So I can easily fix.
- In second scenario, Later in BLOC function,I add `try{} catch(e){}` to show in the UI for the exact detail of error instead of `Loading` State when API contain `null` value. But I face a problem that is it show error like `Null check operator used on a null value` not only on UI screen but also in console but I can't find automatically (mean at first scenario, from console can check which value contain from console ) which detail API value contain `null` and manually check the API and model. It only show error in console about abstract fact of the model class that contain `null`.

So how can I fix that problem? I want to not only show error on screen instead of loading when API contain `null` value but also want to check automatically `null` value from console.

This is my code and show error for **first scenario** without `try catch` and `exception` state

```
getNotificationDetail({required String notificationId}) async {
    await _notificationRepository
        .getNotificationDetail(
      getNewNotificationEndPoint: END_POINT_NOTIFICATION_DETAIL,
      notificationId: notificationId,
    )
        .then(
          (responseValue) {
        _notificationDetailController.sink.add(MessageState.loading);
        if (responseValue?.messageState == MessageState.data) {
          notificationDetailModel = responseValue!.data;
          notificationDetailData = notificationDetailModel!.data;
          _notificationDetailController.sink.add(MessageState.data);
        } else if (responseValue?.messageState == MessageState.requestError) {
          errorHandlingModel = responseValue?.data;
          _notificationDetailController.sink.add(MessageState.requestError);
        } else if (responseValue?.messageState == MessageState.serverError) {
          _notificationDetailController.sink.add(MessageState.serverError);
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

```
E/flutter (22630): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int'
E/flutter (22630): #0      new NewNotificationCountData.fromJson (XXXXXXXXXX/model/notification_model/new_notification_count_model.dart:39:19)
```

---

This is my code and show error for **second scenario** with `try catch` and `exception` state

```
getNotificationDetail({required String notificationId}) async {
    try {
      await _notificationRepository
          .getNotificationDetail(
        getNewNotificationEndPoint: END_POINT_NOTIFICATION_DETAIL,
        notificationId: notificationId,
      )
          .then(
        (responseValue) {
          _notificationDetailController.sink.add(MessageState.loading);
          if (responseValue?.messageState == MessageState.data) {
            notificationDetailModel = responseValue!.data;
            notificationDetailData = notificationDetailModel!.data;
            _notificationDetailController.sink.add(MessageState.data);
          } else if (responseValue?.messageState == MessageState.requestError) {
            errorHandlingModel = responseValue?.data;
            _notificationDetailController.sink.add(MessageState.requestError);
          } else if (responseValue?.messageState == MessageState.serverError) {
            _notificationDetailController.sink.add(MessageState.serverError);
          }
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      errorMessage = e.toString();
      _notificationDetailController.sink.add(MessageState.exception);
    }
  }
```

```
The following _CastError was thrown building StreamBuilder<MessageState>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<MessageState, AsyncSnapshot<MessageState>>#aa511):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<MessageState> StreamBuilder:file:///XXXXXXXXXXX/lib/modules/notifications/view_items/notification_detail_body.dart:29:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
```

Comment: replace `catch (e)` with `catch (e, st)` and use `st` object to get the details, more https://dart.dev/language/error-handling#catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using with **StackTrace (st)** `try{} catch(e,st){}` solved what I expected. Thanks for answering @pskink comment.

So I change my code with

```
getNotificationDetail({required String notificationId}) async {
    try {
      await _notificationRepository
          .getNotificationDetail(
        getNewNotificationEndPoint: END_POINT_NOTIFICATION_DETAIL,
        notificationId: notificationId,
      )
          .then(
        (responseValue) {
          _notificationDetailController.sink.add(MessageState.loading);
          if (responseValue?.messageState == MessageState.data) {
            notificationDetailModel = responseValue!.data;
            notificationDetailData = notificationDetailModel!.data;
            _notificationDetailController.sink.add(MessageState.data);
          } else if (responseValue?.messageState == MessageState.requestError) {
            errorHandlingModel = responseValue?.data;
            _notificationDetailController.sink.add(MessageState.requestError);
          } else if (responseValue?.messageState == MessageState.serverError) {
            _notificationDetailController.sink.add(MessageState.serverError);
          }
        },
      );
    } catch (e, st) {
      errorMessage = e.toString();
      _notificationDetailController.sink.add(MessageState.exception);
      print('st === $st');
    }
  }
```